# How to create component in libs via angular schematics webstorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I did create an angular project in nx monorepo. When I created UI lib's I want to use "Angular Schematic..." (look at the picture)

[image: angular schematic...]

But when I use "schematics/component" the files still are generating on my app.

`apps/project/src/app/test-component/..`

[image: prompt]

I generated workspace via `npx create-nx-workspace@latest` and installed `@nrwl/schematics` but still didn't work.

Also, I did provide this code to my angular.json:

```
  "schematics": {
    "@nrwl/schematics:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@nrwl/schematics:library": {
      "prefix": "test",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest",
      "framework": "angular",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@nrwl/schematics:application": {
      "unitTestRunner": "jest",
      "e2eTestRunner": "protractor"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss",
      "spec": true
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "mor"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/schematics",
    "analytics": false
  }
```

Did I forget about some configuration? What I need to do for using angular schematics in webstorm.

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.5
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.5
@schematics/angular             11.0.5
@schematics/update              0.1100.5
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.0.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this problem was in nx/nrwl. Because now I installed nx version@11.2.10 and workspace with angular. Then installed @nrwl/schematics(8.12.11) and everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will face the same issue when running `ng g @schematics/angular:component` in the library dir in terminal; to get the component created in non-default project, try passing `--project` option to `ng g`:

[image]

Comment: But I saw in different project the way what I described. Without pass any parameters. Webstorm automatically found the module where you want to create a component

Comment: this is not about WebStorm, it's about using `ng g` in nx workspaces. Not sure why it works for you in the other project, the one I've tried is a very basic nx workspace